# Fourier Series of $\sin^k(x/2)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm stuck on a seemingly simple problem: What is the fourier Series for $\sin^k(x/2)$? I've tried Mathematica with no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula)
$$
\sin^n\theta = \frac{2}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} (-1)^{(\frac{n-1}{2}-k)} \binom{n}{k} \sin{((n-2k)\theta)} \tag{$n= {}$odd}
$$
$$
\sin^n\theta = \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} + \frac{2}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} (-1)^{(\frac{n}{2}-k)} \binom{n}{k} \cos{((n-2k)\theta)} \tag{$n={}$even}
$$
and 
$$
\mathcal{F}_x\sin(kx/2)=i\sqrt{2\pi}(\delta(k-2\omega)+\delta(k+2\omega)).
$$
Oh you just want the Fourier Series. So (odd) and (even) should be enough.